# How to select radio button using CSS selector if both buttons has same class name

Tags: java, css, selenium-webdriver

[HTL Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pwBt.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgkDZ.png)

I have 2 radio buttons. Now i can select 1st radio button using Css selector as-
button 1 = div.standard.radio

Now how can i select 2nd radio button using css selector?

Attached snapshot.

Comment: why not use ID?

Comment: i don't have id field. Please check attached Screenshot

Comment: can you please create an snippet or JSFiddle?

Comment: your question isn't clear yet, and still you're just adding screenshot. try to create snippet or JSFiddle. or at least write the code here so we can copy and paste it

Comment: `.//label[contains(text(),button 1)]`

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML. Screenshots of HTML are not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You make use of `element ID` / `css class` to be precise
and in case if you don't want to make any changes to HTML part 
You can use pseudo css class

**:nth-child()** 
[MDN nth-child documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

e.g.

> input:nth-child(2) {
>       color: red; }

Comment: how this works? what if you want to select the specific radio button?

Comment: if its second input radio use the number. I use this in cases where there are lot of radio or I don't want to make changes to html by adding id or class. Have a look at MDN documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: I am able to select 1st Radio button, But not 2nd

Comment: Added with question. Please scroll up.

Comment: `sd-radio-picker input[type=radio]:nth-child(1)` for first radio input
`sd-radio-picker input[type=radio]:nth-child(2)` for second radio input

Comment: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"sd-radio-picker input[type=radio]:nth-child(2)"}(..)

Comment: kinldy make a fiddle and share the link

Comment: I tried with xpath-
Button1 =//div[@class='standard radio'][1]

Button 2= //div[@class='standard radio'][2]

Worked for button1, but for 2nd, gave error
Not able to locate element

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add another class name to them so you can select them individually? For example:

```
<div class="standard radio radio-1"></div>
<div class="standard radio radio-2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div.payment-mode .standard.radio{} /* first way */
.payment-methods-list > :nth-child(2) .standard.radio{} /* second way */
```

Comment: Can you tell me what's exact path for button 1 & 2.
Button1=?
button2=?

Comment: button 1=.payment-methods-list > :nth-child(1) .standard.radio{}

Comment: button2= button 1=.payment-methods-list > :nth-child(2) .standard.radio{}

Comment: Got error-
invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified(..)

Comment: try this for 1st = .standard.radio{}

Comment: and 2nd = div.payment-mode .standard.radio{}

Comment: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified(..)

Same error.

I am able to locate 1st button using xapth-//div[@class='standard radio'][1]
but
not ABLE TO LOCATE 2ND BUTTON.